# Exposing and consuming NetTcpBinding from silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I'm trying to expose and consume a WCF service using NetTCPBinding (I have basicHttpBinding working already) but I don't know how to expose it with this new nettcpbinding.

I've read that I may use Microsoft Service Configurator Editor to configure my service but I can't find a "step-by-step" guide so I configured it manually:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Behavior" name="ServiceImplementation">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:4445/Service" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="Service" contract="IService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Now I want to consume it from a Silverlight dll project and I don't know how to try it. If I add a web reference as I do with the http services it doesn't connect to the "net.tcp://localhost:4445/Service" (it rejects the connection).

How should I do it? Do you know any good step by step guide? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not support all bindngs. NetTcpBinding is one that is not supported.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571(v=vs.95).aspx for a list of what is supported.

Comment: So, do you know any good guide to expose and consume a Custom Binding with TcpTransportBindingElement??